# Send sensitive data using POST+application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: http, post

I am trying to implement user authentication process, and I have gone through enormous number of posts and totally agree that using HTTPS is probably best way to transfer username/password from client to server befor hashing.

Just out of curiosity, I want to know : how safe it is to send username/password from client to server using POST method along with enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as this also send form data in encoded form?

PS. I am using GWT for frontend and JAVA for backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending data by way of the body instead of url params is the way to go, but to ensure that is not sniffed out, you must use HTTPS. Otherwise it will be plaintext.
As to how safe? see here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/how-safe-is-ssl

Comment: Hi @genirahul What did you do than? Did you send with HTTPS or with HTTP ? I have a same problem.

Comment: @JohnnyMartin as mentioned in the accepted answer, I sent using JSON in the request body. If you haven't gone through the link in the answer I will suggest you read it.

Comment: I am using spring OAuth2 and in spring configuration the authentication service is exposed via "/oauth/token" that accept POST using type :x-www-form-urlencoded.  I have doubt that it is not save.So did you implemented HTTPS for user credential request ?

Comment: @JohnnyMartin yes, you should implement HTTPS. (not just for user credential request, but for all server communications) . I am really sorry for delay in response.